# SSRS - multiple matrix tables in one Report (Grouped)

Tags: sql, matrix, reporting-services

I am trying to find a way to pass in a parameter that can have multiple values (customer codes). These customer values then show a matrix table:
X column: Months
Y column: Years
Turnover figures in the body.

So this bit was easy. Now I want to be able to pass in more than one customer code and the matrix churns out a new table per customer, ideally when exported to excel it will show one matrix per sheet.

I know the easy answer to this is to just keep running the report over and over for each customer but this question is a matter of interest to see if this is possible.

Thanks in advance to all that can help

Comment: can you try with matrix inside tablix means create a tablix report & bind with Customer & do row grouping on customer & then add a row inside group. Add as subreport your matrix report customer id  of parent

Comment: I like the idea!! I shall get back to you after I have tried it

Comment: it will work.. i just tried :-)

Comment: i answered to that with some screenshots... you can take the reference and relate to your requirement.. i just created dummy, so don't go with values & on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with matrix inside tablix .. i just tried creating a similar report with employee/deprtment

tablix report grouping done on department

[image]

Second, matrix report filtering done by department (take parameter)

[image]

add a row inside group in tablix report and add a matrix report as subreport in that.. pass the parameter department value in subreport ....